# Do animals have souls? If they do is killing them a major sin?

Tags: halal-haram, death, animals, soul

Do animals have souls because one of the major sins that doom one to Hell is killing a soul. The Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) said: 
 “Avoid the seven sins that doom a person to Hell.” We said: What are they, O Messenger of Allah? He said: “Associating others with Allah (shirk); witchcraft; KILLING A SOUL whom Allah has forbidden us to kill, EXCEPT in cases dictated by Islamic law; consuming orphans’ wealth; consuming riba; fleeing from the battlefield; and slandering chaste, innocent women.”

(Narrated by al-Bukhaari and Muslim)

I know that in cases of eating meat and qurbani it is allowed to kill animals but what about insects like ants and spiders? Sometimes in my house we find (in the summer) ants in our house that has gotten into our food. Can we kill them in this case?

Comment: The general ruling is that it is permissible to kill for food, and it is permissible to kill a creature that may harm a person or their property in any way.

Comment: There's already an answer to [Do animals have souls?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/10180/17163) (which I think is decent).

Comment: I think you are understanding the verse too literally, when it says in Arabic killing a SOUL it rather means killing a HUMAN (according to the context). Does the soul even die?